# access constructor using dot operator

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in c++ and i tried to access the constructor method by creating an object and accessing it through an dot operator. In the process i got  errors .Is it normal ? I'm just trying to experiment .If there's a way to do the same please let me know the procedure , i have googled but couldn't find any solution.Below is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class box
{
  public:
    box(double );
  private:
    double width;
};

 box::box(double w)
{
  cout<<"\n I'm inside the constructor ";
  width=w;
}


box::~box()
{
  cout<<"\n I'm inside the desstructor ";

}


int main()
{
  box box1;
  box1.box(10);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to experiemnt .Why a down vote ?

Comment: Note also: a) Your class doesn't have default constructor, which is invoked in `box box1;` line; b) Your destructor is implicitly declared, but you tries to redefine it in global scope.

Comment: @soon i know , i just wanted to see whether we can call the constructor and initialize the member variables of the class.

Comment: Then you just have to initialize your object like this: `box box1(10);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's normal, you cannot call constructor manually. It's not a function. It makes no sense to call c-tor on an already constructed object.

> Because constructors do not have names, they are
> never found during name lookup; however an explicit type conversion using the functional notation (5.2.3)
> will cause a constructor to be called to initialize an object. [ Note: For initialization of objects of class type
> see 12.6. — end note ]

Answer (score 3):

First note that your code does not even compile. We'll get to that in a minute.

This line:

```
box box1;
```

attempts to create a box object. After the ; box1 is a fully fledged box object. Well, it would be if the code could compile. But it can't because box doesn't have a default constructor. You can't create a box instance with no arguments - you must give it a double. In the next line you try to do that, but it's too late - a constructor is only called at object creation.

So you must do this instead:

```
box box1(10.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really make sense to construct an object and then call its constructor again.

The line

```
box box1;
```

creates an instance and calls its default constructor.

You cannot create the same instance again after it's been created. What you're probably looking for is an assignment operator, not a construtor.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense , i was just trying to play around with the code .